# Memory leak in malloc showed by instruments GPUImageFilter Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, malloc, instruments

I'm implementing the instagram like image filters in my app and I'm using GPUImageFilters for that. But when I keep switching to different filter more than 10 times it got crashed then I tried with instruments and found out that there is a large memory allocation in GPUFilter class and its because of `malloc`. As I'm new to memory leak related issues, please help me out! Thanks

Here is the GPUImageFilter code:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput {
    [GPUImageOpenGLESContext useImageProcessingContext];
    [self setFilterFBO];

    CGSize currentFBOSize = [self sizeOfFBO];

    NSUInteger totalBytesForImage = (int)currentFBOSize.width * (int)currentFBOSize.height * 4;
    GLubyte *rawImagePixels = (GLubyte *)malloc(totalBytesForImage); //here its showing the large memory allocation
    glReadPixels(0, 0, (int)currentFBOSize.width, (int)currentFBOSize.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rawImagePixels);

    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, rawImagePixels, totalBytesForImage, dataProviderReleaseCallback);


    CGColorSpaceRef defaultRGBColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGImageRef cgImageFromBytes = CGImageCreate((int)currentFBOSize.width, (int)currentFBOSize.height, 8, 32, 4 * (int)currentFBOSize.width, defaultRGBColorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageFromBytes scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];



    // free(rawImagePixels);
    CGImageRelease(cgImageFromBytes);
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(defaultRGBColorSpace);


    return finalImage; 
}
```

Screenshot from instruments:
[image: Screenshot from instruments]

Comment: Why is the free commented out?

Comment: @Jim Its just making the final image to disappear. Thats why its commented out.

Comment: Are you freeing the final image each time?  When it crashes, are there many of these mallocs hanging around.  Since the final image embodies (or whatever) the malloc, then it needs to be freed.  Every malloc needs a matching free.

Comment: @Jim Actually its getting freed by the line `CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, rawImagePixels, totalBytesForImage, dataProviderReleaseCallback);`, so when we try to free it again it causes crash.

Comment: If it's freeing it, then why is it still around??  Are there 10 of them aeound when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

malloc doesn't free when whatever it allocates on one thread is deallocated on another.

Wrap your code in this:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

```
// malloc and whatever other code goes here...
```

});